# Ruby shuffle! each array inside array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, arrays

I'm trying to make a quiz, so I have many questions with many answers. I'm able to shuffle the questions, so they don't appear with the same order everytime.

`q = Question.all().shuffle!`

Then, I try to shuffle all the answers for each question:

`q.each{ |i| i.answers.shuffle! }`

But when I iterate over `q` on the view I always get the answers for each question in the same order every time. Any hint on what am I doing wrong?

EDIT

If I do `@question = Question.find(1,2,3).shuffle!` I get:

```
 [ #<Question id: 1, contenido: "lorem ipsum 1", created_at: "2014-02-09 13:13:56", updated_at: "2014-02-09 13:13:56">
#<Question id: 3, contenido: "lorem ipsum 3", created_at: "2014-02-09 13:13:56", updated_at: "2014-02-09 13:13:56">, 
#<Question id: 2, contenido: "lorem ipsum2", created_at: "2014-02-09 13:13:56", updated_at: "2014-02-09 13:13:56"> ]
```

If I do `@question.first().answers` I get an array like this:

```
#<ActiveRecord::Associations::CollectionProxy [
#<Answer id: 1, contenido: "Black", correcta: true, created_at: "2014-02-09 13:13:56", updated_at: "2014-0213:13:56", question_id: 1>, 
#<Answer id: 2, contenido: "Blue", correcta: false, created_at: "2014-02-09 13:13:56", updated_at: "2014-02-09 13:13:56", question_id: 1>, 
#<Answer id: 3, contenido: "Yellow", correcta: false, created_at: "2014-02-09 13:13:56", updated_at: "2014-02-09 13:13:56", question_id: 1>]>
```

My controller method looks like this:

```
def quiz
    @questions = Question.find(1,2).shuffle!
    @questions.each{ |i| i.answers.shuffle! }
end
```

And In the view I do this:

```
<% @questions.each_with_index do |pregunta, index| %>
    <div class="question-item <% if index == 0 %>current<% end %>">
    <p><%= index + 1  %>- <%= pregunta.contenido %></p>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "form[][pregunta]", pregunta.id  %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "form[][respuesta]", "" %>
    <ul>
        <% pregunta.answers.each do |respuesta| %>
            <li><span class="radio" data-id="<%= respuesta.id %>"></span><span><%= respuesta.contenido %></span></li>   
        <% end %>
    </ul>   
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: Crazy! It shouldn't happen so. :)

Comment: Can you post a sample array of questions and answers?

Comment: How are you printing on the view ? I want to see also the answers method, how did you define it ?

Comment: May be `i.answers` is giving you array object, which is a `#dup` of original one, thus you are doing **shuffling**, on the copy, not the actual one, thus no change you are seeing. Although it is all are possible reasons, I don't know what actually your code has. Here is one example for the same - `>> a = [[1,2,3],[3,6,4]]
=> [[1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 4]]
>> a.each { |e| e.dup.shuffle! }
=> [[1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 4]]
>> a.each { |e| e.dup.shuffle! }
=> [[1, 2, 3], [3, 6, 4]]`.

Comment: see there although I called `shuffle!`, but no change in the original `a` entries, as all times i did on a **dup** object of the entries of `a`.

Comment: I added my actual code above.

Comment: have you tried `@questions.each{ |i| i.answers.shuffle! }` ?

Comment: Sorry, I was doing that Abdo, just corrected my code above.

Comment: Can you try `@questions.each{ |i| i.answers.to_a.shuffle!) }` ?

Comment: Tried that Abdo, same result.

Comment: If it's a copy, how can I change the original @arup-rakshit?

Answer (score 0):

I'd probably do this as I was accessing them, so in the view...

```
<% @questions.shuffle!.each_with_index do |pregunta, index| %>
    <div class="question-item <% if index == 0 %>current<% end %>">
        <p><%= index + 1  %>- <%= pregunta.contenido %></p>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "form[][pregunta]", pregunta.id  %>
        <%= hidden_field_tag "form[][respuesta]", "" %>
        <ul>
            <% pregunta.answers.shuffle!.each do |respuesta| %>
                <li><span class="radio" data-id="<%= respuesta.id %>"></span><span><%= respuesta.contenido %></span></li>   
            <% end %>
        </ul>   
    </div>
 <% end %>
```

Comment: That's why I ended up doing to make it work. Still I want to understand how do I modify an array while I am iterating over it.

Comment: You should have been able to do 

@questions = @questions.each{ |i| i.answers.shuffle! }

shuffle! returns new arrays, making no modification to the array you are accessing. So you'd need to assign the result (or use shuffle without the '!' symbol